# Gradually slowing down linear velocity of box2d body

Tags: cocos2d-x, box2d

I am currently developing a billiard game using box2d physics engine. When I apply force to main ball, it will gain constant speed.

How to gradually slow the body?

P.S. Gravity is set to zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set linear damping to that body. Lets say 5

body->setLinearDamping(5);

Comment: After setting linearDamping, the velocity is forever smaller but never goes to 0. So you might see the ball keep running even the travel distance is really small.